# When will Ubuntu 20.04.5 be released

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I can not find any info for this point release. No date on wiki and discourse. This release is very important, because in this release it has kernel 5.15.

Comment: Looking at the previous LTS dates, I suspect that it will be released at August 2022: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @FedKad Yeah, I was going to say the same. There have been some slight discrepancies and 18.04.6 released in September instead of February but, other than that, they're all pretty much in line.

Comment: @FedKad Actually, it looks like 18.04 [was only supposed to have 5 point releases](https://9to5linux.com/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released-with-boothole-patches-latest-security-updates) and 18.04.6 was extra so that's why the date was off.

Comment: The norm is .5 only for LTS releases; .2 thru .5 contain kernel stack upgrades from the non-LTS releases; any subsequent releases are usually the result of security patches that prevent prior ISOs from booting; ie. fully patched systems would no longer boot 18.04.5 media due *boothole* patches requiring [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/), `grub` issues for[16.04.7](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/) etc.  Minimal notice for later releases is given, can be just days (7-28) so they're often a little rushed.

Comment: September 1st 2022 per the link in the answer regarding release schedule

Answer (score 3):

When the date is known it'll appear on the release schedule

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule

Even without the date currently known, a rough clue can be gained from the prior '*equivalent*' release, ie. [18.04.5](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) and adding two years.

*Dailies* (of 20.04.5) are available right now, but they don't currently have the 5.15 kernel stack you want; but they'll become available well before ISO release date, as will the *edge* kernel for installed systems.

Extra details

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack#hwe-16.04-edge

(Note: the wiki page talks about 16.04's edge kernel, but details apply to later releases too)

The date will be added to the wiki after Ubuntu 22.04's release and focus turns to Ubuntu 22.04.1 & Ubuntu 20.04.5.